# Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a function inside DAO Class inside which i am passing a value to my store procedure by using NameStoredProcedureQuery but the code showing me an error on the last line complaining about "insert enumbody" i don't know this problem is related to eclipse or my code

```
    public void myfucn(Double x){

         @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                         name="Calculate",
                         procedureName = "Calculate",

          parameters = {   @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type=Double.class, name="x")

                       }
                                )  // * red cross on this line
            StoredProcedureQuery query =  this.em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("Calculate");
                     query.setParameter("x",x);
                     query.execute();

    }
```

Comment: Could you please format your code legibly?

Answer (score 1):

`@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` is only allowed at class level not within a method.

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(...) // move to here
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
```